# Android after any changes Firebase Database activity/fragment is closing

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

i have developed an Android app and I used Firebase for authentication, database and storage. In my app there is navigationview and there are 5 6 fragments. For example there is a profile fragment, users can change personal information in there, but after save button profile fragment is crashing and app is going back to HomePageActivity. There is same problem on uploading images in a activity. Users upload some wound photos, from an activity ,which is reached from a fragment. However after uploading photo to the storage and sending information to database activity is crashing and app is going back to HomePageActivty. I used both addValueEventListener and addListenerForSingleValueEvent, but problem is not been solved. Could you help me? 
Here is a example:

```
 btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save();
            bringInfo();
            Toast.makeText(ProfilActivity.this,"Info changes is saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

 private void save() {

        myRef.child("kullanicilar").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                        Map<String, Object> postValues = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                                                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                            postValues.put(snapshot.getKey(),snapshot.getValue());
                                                        }
                                                        postValues.put("ad", (etNameH.getText().toString()).substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+(etNameH.getText().toString()).substring(1));
                                                        postValues.put("soyad", (etSurnameH.getText().toString()).substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+(etSurnameH.getText().toString()).substring(1));
                                                        postValues.put("hastane", etCalistigiKurumPr.getText().toString());
                                                        myRef.child("kullanicilar").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).updateChildren(postValues);
                                                    }

                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                                                }
                );
}
 private void bringInfo() {

    myRef.child("kullanicilar")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                etNameH.setText(user.getAd());
                etSurnameH.setText(user.getSoyad());
                etCalistigiKurumPr.setText(user.getHastane());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code and error logs. See [ask] for more help.

Comment: codes are too long for sharing. there is no error logs. i could not solve this problem

Comment: If there was a crash, there are most likely error logs; check [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat). We can't possibly help diagnose your issue without seeing any code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: actually this problem is not seeing always, some time activity is crashing some time not.

Comment: is problem about asynctask?

Comment: It very well could be. `AsyncTask` is [notoriously problematic](https://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/). I would recommend switching to [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) (using a `ViewModel`) and/or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). But again, it's impossible to tell without any crash logs, or your `AsyncTask` code.

Comment: thank you very much try to get the error by testing a little more.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: app is not crashing, only fragment or activity is closing and app is going back to main activity/home page activity, so i can't find any error on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

remove calling bringInfo() from btnSave. OnClickListner method and put under onDataChange method try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    save();
    // bringInfo() remove from here
    Toast.makeText(ProfilActivity.this,"Info changes is
            saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//        *****Remaining Code*****
    bringInfo() put it here
}
```